# Cloning from existing master Bitbucket repo and working in a new branch

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket, git-branch

I am a git noob. I working with android studio and what I want to do is, get project from the existing master repo in bitbucket and then create a new branch and start working in the new branch.

The master branch is an eclipse project and I'll be working with studio, so whatever changes I make must be in a new branch and must not alter the master branch.

If someone can give me a brief idea of how can I do this and the command lines if possible, I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the repo, creating a new branch, and using this branch, is basically

```
git clone url://to/bitbucket/repo
git checkout -b myNewBranch
```

That being said, according to your description, it might be simpler to not create a new branch. Indeed, if you create a new branch because you don't want to mix eclipse and android studio files, and if you commit your android studio files in your branch, then you'll never be able to merge your changes back.